# Highlight Dates dynamically of datetimepicker - The plugin used for datepicker is Jquery datetimepicker full

Tags: date, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

```
 $("#myDate").datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'Y-m-d',
        scrollInput: false,
        value: new Date(),
            onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
                LoadBasedOnDate();
        }
        ,
            highlightedDates: [
                dateArray[0]

        ]


        });
```

dateArray contains a set of dates as array for example [ "2020-03-17"  "2020-03-18","2020-03-20"]
    Here dateArray[0] ,  "2020-03-17"  is highlighted  .
    How can highlight every date from dateArray  in  datepicker?  jquery datetimepicker full plugin is 
    used

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question. You need to use **beforeShowDay** function in the jquery ui datepicker. In that you can compare all dates with your dateArray. Add **css-class-to-highlight** this class if match is found.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
           var dateArray  = [ "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18","2020-03-20"];
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    // First convert all values in dateArray to date Object and compare with current date
                    var dateFound =  dateArray.find(function(item) {
                        var formattedDate = new Date(item);
                        return date.toLocaleDateString() === formattedDate.toLocaleDateString();
                    })
                     // check if date is in your array of dates
                    if(dateFound) {
                        // if it is return the following.
                        return [true, 'css-class-to-highlight', 'tooltip text'];
                    } else {
                        // default
                        return [true, '', ''];
                    }

                }
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
       

        .css-class-to-highlight a{
           background-color: blue !important;
           color: #fff !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="NonBusinessDays" />
           <div id="datepicker"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: datetimepicker , and datepickers are bit different , I was asking for the one in datetimepicker would you help with that ? Cant change the datepicker plugin in the middle ! Anyway thanks bud @prathameshk73